# setting a destination for uploaded Images in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

i am a little confused about how to set a destination for an uploaded images in zend frameowrk 2

i followed this great tutorial [here](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/zend-framework-2-creating-upload-form-file-validation/)

and have managed to upload my images. however, i need to upload the image to my public folder. at present i am only able to upload to a folder within the module i am working on.

i.e:

```
 $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();  
 $adapter->setDestination(dirname(__DIR__).'/testImage');
```

what is the equivalent direname(*DIR*) that would allow me to set the address to an alternative directory or to the directory in my public folder.

thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: Simply `setDestination('/public/foo')`, but you shouldn't upload data to `/public`

Comment: thank you. but is there a reason why i should not upload to the public folder. the uploaded photos will be used for displaying images on the web pages. i was under the impression that only images held in the public folder could be shown on a web page